# What is the reason of this segmentation fault?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, malloc

Consider the following snippet:

```
void init ()
{
int i,j;
ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);

  X=w.ws_col;
  Y=w.ws_row - 9;
  printf("X=%d,Y=%d\n",X,Y); // X and Y looks good, 144 and 32
  getch();
  Terrain=malloc(Y);
  for(i=0;i<Y;i++)
    Terrain[i]=malloc(X);
    printf("Created terrain\n"); //OK
Terrain[6][0]=getch();
  printf("%x\n",Terrain[6][0]); getch(); //No problem accessing Terrain[6][0]
  for (i = 0; i < Y; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < X-1; j++)
        {
            if ((i == 0) || (j == 0) || (j == (X - 2)) || (i == (Y - 1)))
                {printf("%d:%d\n",i,j);Terrain[i][j] = '#';printf(" '#'OK\n");} //seg fault in this line for i=6,j=0
            else
                {printf("%d:%d\n",i,j);Terrain[i][j] = ' ';printf(" '_'OK\n");}
        }
        printf("%d:%d",i,X-1);
        Terrain[i][X - 1] = '\0';printf(" 'o'OK\n");
    }
}
```

Out put is something like this...

> ...
>
> 5:141
>
> '_'OK
>
> 5:142
>
> '#'OK
>
> 5:143 'o'OK
>
> 6:0
>
> Segmentation fault (core dumped)
>
> dipto@dipto-VirtualBox:~$

There is no problem if I use static array of same size, i.e. 144 and 32.
Am I missing or overlooking something?

Comment: should be `Terrain=malloc(Y * sizeof(char *))`

Comment: ok, but that doesn't help..

Comment: run it through gdb and get a backtrace so you know which line the issue is. also `Terrain[6][0]=getch();` shouldn't be accessed until `Terrain[6]` is allocated..

Comment: @amdixon, yes, `Terrain=malloc(Y * sizeof(char *))` works. I did another mistake. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not show key variables, like X and in particular Y.

When allocating memory you usually need a multiplier to account for the byte size of each member of the array. "short"s usually need 2. "int"s a tricky these days and can be 4 or 8. Something along the line of `Terrain=malloc(Y*sizeof(Terrain[0]))`.

Without the multiplier you do not allocate enough memory and your survival depends on how the memory is allocated and what gets stomped on when you go beyond the end of actual memory.